# How To Use onchange() to Display Another Select List?

Tags: javascript, html

Need some help here. Seemed to be a little stuck. To keep it short and sweet, I have a select list that contains several options. Now, my end goal is, if I select a specific option, I want to display another select list called Modules and within this select list also have several options available to select. The options I am targeting within list "ProductDet_Product" is DocAve 6 and DocAve 5 as shown below.

```js
function loadmodule($i) {
  if ($i = "DocAve 6") {
    var x = document.createElement("SELECT");
    x.setAttribute("id", "loadDA6module");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var z = document.createElement("option");
    z.setAttribute("value", "Administrator")
    var t = document.createTextNode("Administrator");
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("loadDA6module").appendChild)(z);
  }
}
```

```html
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 534px;">
  <p><small>Product
        (Project):

        <select id="ProductDet_Product" 
          onchange="loadmodule(document.getElementById(this).options[document.getElementById(this).selectedIndex].value);">

          <option>APIA</option>
          <option>ARIS (Risk Intelligence System)</option>
          <option>Citizens Services</option>
          <option>Compliance Guardian</option>
          <option>Compliance Guardian Online</option>
          <option>Discovery Tool</option>
          <option value="DocAve 6">DocAve 6</option>
          <option value="DocAve 5">DocAve 5</option>
          <option>File Share Navigator</option>
          <option>File Share Navigator Online</option>
          <option>Governance Automation</option>
          <option>Governance Automation Online</option>
          <option>Meetings</option>
          <option>Meetings Online</option>
          <option>Office Connect</option>
          <option>Perimeter</option>
          <option>Perimeter Online</option>
          <option>PDF Aggregator</option>
          <option>Salesforce Backup</option>
          <option>Secure Publisher</option>
          <option>Watermark</option>
      </select>
    </small>
  </p>
</td>
```

If I were to choose either DocAve 5 or DocAve 6, I would like to display another select list underneath this list that would contain options as I described above.

When I select DocAve 6, the additional select list does not appear. Would love some assistance here if you dont mind! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

- Create another select list in your HTML, and set it's CSS display property to `none`

`<select id="hiddenSelect">`

- In your `onchange()` callback for the visible `select`, you then check if the selected value=="DocAve 6" and, if so, set the display property of the other list to `block`

```
    <select id="ProductDet_Product" onchange="showHiddenSelect()">

    function showHiddenSelect() {
    var result = document.getElementById('ProductDet_Product').value;
    if (result=="DocAve 5") {
    document.getElementById("hiddenSelect").style.display = "block";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @shalvah! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to get the selected option like that. simply pass this as argument to `onchange` and get the value:

```
<select id="ProductDet_Product" onchange="loadmodule(this);">
```

Then in your load module check `.value` of the parameter:

```
function loadmodule(activities) {
    console.log(activities.value);
    if(activities.value == "test")
    {
        addOtherSelect();
    }    
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wb1asm4SjwYF3kPTXDqK?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you @Yaser. Much appreciated!